# preg_match words followed by numbers

Tags: php, preg-match, preg-match-all

I've got the following string:

```
Query_time: 77.571216 Lock_time: 2.793139 Rows_sent: 20 Rows_examined: 4654071
```

How would i go about placing each number into a variable?
eg:

```
$query_time    = 77.571216;  
$lock_time     = 2.793139;
$rows_sent     = 20;
$rows_examined = 4654071;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if (preg_match('/Query_time: ([0-9.]+) Lock_time: ([0-9.]+) Rows_sent: ([0-9.]+) Rows_examined: ([0-9.]+)/', $string, $matches)) {
    list($query_time, $lock_time, $rows_sent, $rows_examined) =
            array_slice($matches, 1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$str = 'Query_time: 77.571216 Lock_time: 2.793139 Rows_sent: 20 Rows_examined: 4654071';
list($null, $query_time, $lock_time, $rows_sent, $rows_examined) = preg_split('/\S+:/',$str);
```

Answer (score 1):

Almost the same answer as [k102](https://stackoverflow.com/users/709711/k102) with a slight change, I'm using the flag [PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php), so there's no need to have a $null var at the beginning of the list :)

```
$str = 'Query_time: 77.571216 Lock_time: 2.793139 Rows_sent: 20 Rows_examined: 4654071';
list($query_time, $lock_time, $rows_sent, $rows_examined) = preg_split('/\S+:/',$str, 0, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```